# What type of font is lst?

Tags: css, import, fonts

I have a font type called AdobeFnt21.lst. I'm trying to import it into my CSS, but I don't know what lst stands for or what to specify for format. In other words, I don't know what to type here:

```
    @@font-face {
        font-family: "AdobeFnt21";
        src: url("assets/fonts/AdobeFnt21.lst") format( ****** What goes here? ****** ),
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can find some answers here: https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign/missing-font-how-to-install-lst/td-p/3399836?page=1

But I don't think that is a font.

You'll need the correct files.

Comment: Huh. I think indeed, you're right. Opening that file in Notepad++, it's definitely not a font file but a sort of meta-data file about other fonts. Thanks for pointing that out.